# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'epayment.dubai.ae'. .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: vb.net, ssl, x509certificate

I am getting this error from my website, it works when I reset IIS for a while, but then it starts to throw the same error and will work again after I reset it again.

I have tried to change the GLobal_asax application_start securityProtocol for:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


If System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls) Then
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

All of this returned the same result

I am using iis 8.5 , windows server 2012

Comment: i have added permission to IIS AppPool/.NET v4.5 Classic user which is the appPool name , i will wait now to see if this solve the problem

Comment: it didnt work still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have installed a root certificate from the payment provider which solve the problem